# too few arguments sprintf

Tags: php, printf

I have done this many times before, to re-use a value passed into the sprintf() function.  But this code is returning a "Warning: sprintf() [function.sprintf]: Too few arguments in..." message.

Here is the code:

```
$search_clause = sprintf(" (msgBody LIKE %%%1$s%% OR msgSubject LIKE '%%%1$s%%' ) ", mysql_real_escape_string($match1));
```

Ideally the value of $match1 will be inserted into the segment of the SQL WHERE clause shown above - twice, each wrapped by '%' characters for a wildcard search.

If $match1 = "test", the resulting string value of $search_clause would be:

```
(msgBody LIKE '%test' OR msgSubject LIKE '%test%' )
```

What is the obvious mistake I'm making??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `$s` is probably getting interpreted as a variable (see [variable expansion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)). Try using single quotes instead:

```
$search_clause = sprintf(' (msgBody LIKE "%%%1$s%%" OR msgSubject LIKE "%%%1$s%%" ) ', mysql_real_escape_string($match1));
```

Comment: Not sure if stackoverflow did it or not, but my code actually has single quotes -- not double.

Comment: Ahh -- different quote.   I see what you mean now.  That fixed it. 

I had double quotes wrapping the first argument to the sprintf() function such as :   sprintf("string here", $value);   

but should have used:   sprintf('string here', $value);

THANKS!

Comment: @Brian Bell: I meant the whole PHP string declaration and not the MySQL string declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Just escape the `$` as `\$`.

```
$search_clause = sprintf(" (msgBody LIKE %%%1\$s%% OR msgSubject LIKE '%%%1\$s%%' ) ", mysql_real_escape_string($match1));
                                             ^                             ^
```